What Is the Best Way to Persist ML Models Outside a K8S Cluster with Local Directory Like Interface?
Project Description
A standard machine learning training and inference pipeline, as in the following diagram, but needs to be part of a Kubernetes cluster.
Training
Triggered as a cronjob, fetches the latest data, does feature engineering, trains and persists a model using tf.keras.Model.save (which uses protocol buffer to save the architecture under the hood). The implementation is all using Python.
Inference
Maybe as a cronjob, or as a service (I am still figuring out the architecture), but in any case, it will also fetch the feature data from the database, load the trained model, will perform feature transformation and inference, to save the final result in the database. But this container has to be replicated (as in a K8S Deployment), to ensure availability and scalability.

Challenge
I got the database and containerisation of the training and inference all nailed. But not sure about what kind of technologies, and resource help me implement the model persistence (and eventual loading) in a clean, performant and maintainable manner. These are some of the desirable properties that I am looking for

The training and inference codes should be able to treat the persistence location as a mounted local directory, i.e. they should not be aware of the implementation.
The persistence location itself should be outside the cluster, and if necessary, I should be able to load models from there from outside the cluster too.
Good performance is enough, but I don't need extreme latency sensitivity.
Some basic locking mechanism, specifically ensuring that inference replicas can read the model simultaneously with read locks, and the training pod can write exclusively with a write lock would be ideal.
The choice of storage should be agnostic of the specific Kubernetes cluster, i.e. I want to develop and test using minikube on my laptop, but then the same manifests should be able to run on something like a managed GKE cluster.

Options Considered
I am trying to read up on options like s3 bucket (does not provide a direct directory like read/write interface), MinIo (similar), JuiceFS (which seems to be another layer to maintain), and KubernetesPersistentVolume (still part of the cluster), but cannot figure the correct way to combine them into what I am seeking. Is JuiceFS backed by S3 buckets good? Or some custom resource within K8S itself can help me interact with the S3 as a mounted volume?
So some ideas around this will be greatly appreciated. If any part of the question/architecture is unclear, ask in the comments.

I think you need persistent volumes to keep the info visible in pod and stored outside Kubernetes (if you deploy k8s on local machines( : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/

@RomeoNinov thanks, will the choice of technologies have to depend on where the Kubernetes is deployed? I would ideally want a cloud storage technology that works with just minikube on my local machine during development, but seamlessly scales when I go to managed GKE clusters. So can we make the storage mechanism agnostic of K8s implementation?

Della, firs please add this clarification in to the question, comments are ephemeral. Second AFAIK Minio can do the work, it can use S3 as backed to storage (acting more or less like proxy). Something like: https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/administration/object-management/transition-objects-to-s3.html

Also check here: https://blog.min.io/batch-replication-s3-minio/
